# React router on change function throws error on first call

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to implement authentication with react and react-router i looked at the [auth-flow](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow) example on react-routers git. But i keep getting an error on the first time i call the auth.login function

index.js:36071 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'onChange' of undefined(…)

If i call the function again everything works as expected

The error is at this line:

this.onChange(false);

React-router definition:

```
<Router history={appHistory}>
<Route path='/' component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={FrontPage}/>
  <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
  <Route path="vikar" component={Vikar} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
</Route>
```

App Component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.router = context.router;
    this.state = {
      LoggedIn: auth.loggedIn()
    };
    this.updateAuth = this.updateAuth.bind(this)
  }
  updateAuth(loggedIn) {
    this.setState({
      loggedIn
    });
    if(loggedIn){
    this.router.push('/');
    }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    auth.onChange = this.updateAuth
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Login Component

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          email: "",
          password: "",
          error: "" 
       };
      this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this)
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }
  handleChange(field, e) {
    var nextState = {}
    nextState[field] = e.target.value
    this.setState(nextState)
  }
  submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    auth.login(this.state.email, this.state.password, (loggedIn) => {
         if (!loggedIn) {
            return this.setState({ error: "Login Failed" })
       }
  })
  }
   render() {
      return (
        <div style={inlineStyles}>
          <PageHeader title={'Login ViogTo'}/>
          <Page>
            <InputBox onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'email')} placeholder={"Email"} icon={'FaEnvelope'} type={"email"}/>
            <InputBox onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'password')} placeholder={"Kodeord"} icon={'FaLock'} type={"password"}/>
            <p>{this.state.error}</p>
            <Button onClick={this.submitForm} label={'Login'}/>
          </Page>
        </div>
      );
   }
}
```

Auth.js

```
module.exports = {
  login(email, pass, cb) {
    cb = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
    var token = (typeof window !== "undefined") ? localStorage.token : undefined;
    if (token) {
      if (cb) cb(true)
      this.onChange(true)
      return
    }
    axios.post(config.serverURL + 'login', {
      email: email,
      password: pass
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data)
      localStorage.token = response.data
      if (cb) cb(true)
      this.onChange(true)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      if (cb) cb(false)
      this.onChange(false)
    });
  },
  onChange(loggedIn) {},
  getToken() {
    return (typeof window !== "undefined") ? localStorage.token : undefined;
  },
  logout(cb) {
    delete localStorage.token
    if (cb) cb()
    this.onChange(false)
  },
  loggedIn() {
    return !!((typeof window !== "undefined") ? localStorage.token : undefined)
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `this` context in your `login` method does not transfer outside the promise scope. `this` is the function. Why not just return immediately?

Comment: But why is it working on second call to the auth.login function? So instead of calling the onChange function just return true/false?

Comment: Maybe it is because you are binding auth.onChange in the `componentWillMount`.

Comment: But since App is a parent component to login where shouldn't it be in the same scope. I can't tell the difference between the example at react-router git and mine